# Trying to click on a spinner item to open new view

Tags: java, android, spinner

Hello my dear stackoverflow geniuses.

I am trying to open a new view through a selected spinner item. The following code does now give me an error but it crashes the app. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
        searchType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 4)

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is my Toast message!!! =)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

    });
```

Thank you for your awesome help!

LOGCAT

[image]

It appears that my previous LogCat was bugged. This is the real Image of my LogCat
[image]

Comment: Can you post your LogCat please?

Comment: what I dont understand is why YouTube is there. I am not using or referencing to YouTube in any way shape or form

Comment: Are you sure youtube stuff is coming from your application? It can be from different process id, try to look at bottom of the LogCat after your application crashed.

Comment: The LogCat I uploaded is the only one showing. It only happens when I add the above code. When I remove it the app works perfectly. LogCat keeps repeating the same LogCat.